# Missing/deleted comments

Tags: discussion, comments

This answer:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/227385/43191 had a lot of comments associated with it and now all but one are gone. Anybody know why? Or how?

Comment: Likely deleted due to getting out of hand/too chatty, like always in those cases

Comment: Yet one comment inviting replies was was left. Odd...

Comment: You took a legitimate technical inquiry, interpreted it as insulting,  and turned it into a petty argument. The only odd thing were  your responses.

Comment: Which "legitimate technical inquiry" would that be, specifically?

Answer (score 5):

You've been around here long enough that you should know comments, especially lengthy comment chains, get deleted occasionally.  I didn't see this question originally, but guessing from your post and people's likely reaction, there was probably a lot of back and forth between you and one or more people arguing about something.

**Comments are not for content**.  They are supposed to be for short discussion with the author of the post.  This could be to ask for clarification, a short related question, pointing out a problem, etc.  Ideally, the result of comments is edits to the post.

When someone asks a quick related question, it's OK and common to answer with a quick comment.  However, you should always be asking yourself whether your response (if you are the post author) should instead be a modification to the post.

We're all guilty of answering quick questions in a comment with another comment.  That's OK, but ***alway keep in mind that comments may be cleaned up***.  If what you are saying is quick and dirty, then you shouldn't care if it gets deleted after a while.  If it's meant to be permanent, then it doesn't belong in a comment.  Modify your post instead.

The one remaining comment is pointing out a issue with your post that you didn't address.  I suspect that it didn't get deleted because it's point is unresolved and still valid (the zener can't handle the power if the load is removed).

Comment: Nicely put, Olin, Thank you. :-)